# Containers class owner's child object having to add components into his parent's container problem

Tags: java, swing, applet, containers

I am having problems dealing with containers and components in my JApplet.
I don't put my code because I think there is no need for it.

The main class owns the getContentPane().

Another class (let's call it class1) owns a JLayeredPane() and components that are added to it.

Another class (let's call it class2) only have components to show.

At the init(), the main class adds class1's JLayeredPane().

At a later time, class1 adds its components to its JLayeredPane(), and create a new object from class2.

Class2 is supposed to generate a variable number of components (the number of components and their properties change with time), but can't add them to class1's JLayeredPane().

How can I have the class2 components to be showed ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Three ways
1. Pass JLayeredPane() to the class2's constructor or a method
2. Class2 has methods that return the components that Class1 can
   add to JLayeredPane()
3. Pass Class1's object to class2 which will call Class1's method through
   a known interface that Class1 implements (a callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

Give a reference of class1 to class2

```
....In Class1 code
Class2 two = new Class2();
two.setClass1Ref( this );
```

And each time `two` adds new components set them to `one`

```
... in Class2 code 


 Class1 one ...

 JComponent newComponent = .... 

 one.add( newComponent ); // onw.add delegates to its own JLayaredPane
```

If you don't want to have a reference of `Class1` in `Class2` then you can add a callback method on or something like a [ContainerListener](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ContainerListener.html)